# Как заблокировать спецсимвол &times;

Tags: javascript, html

Всем доброго вечера! У меня такая проблема. Есть задание сделать меню с ценами и чтобы их можно было добавлять и удалять из заказа. После нажатия на кнопку оплаты, у меня должны блокироваться все кнопки с позициями, чтобы ничего нельзя было добавить в заказ и удалить из него. Блокировку кнопок для добавления я сделал, а вот как мне заблокировать спец символ ×, чтобы при нажатии на него в браузере позиция не удалялась? Обычная блокировка для кнопок не подходит, он ее игнорирует. Помогите пожалуйста.
Вот вырезка как я блокировал кнопки:

```
document.querySelector('.payed').addEventListener('click', function() {
document.querySelector('.stuffing_cheese_small').disabled = true;
document.querySelector('.stuffing_potato_small').disabled = true;
}
```

И вот как я создал спецсимвол через js:

```
var deleteIcon = document.createElement('span');
deleteIcon.className = 'delete-position';
deleteIcon.innerHTML = '&times;';
bindDeleteEvent(deleteIcon);
```

(из комментария:)

мне больше подходит вариант с removeEventListener. Только вот не могу понять, у меня есть вот такая функция:

```
function bindDeleteEvent(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var target = event.target;
        var closestPosition = target.closest('.position');
        closestPosition.remove();
    })
}
```

Как должен это должно выглядеть, вот так?:

```
document.removeEventListener('click',  bindDeleteEvent);
```

Все, вот ответ на мой вопрос, если кому интересно:

```
 Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.delete-position')).forEach(function(element) {
        element.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
      });
```

Comment: А при чём тут спецсимвол? Если заменить `&times;` на `jfgh4iheiuv` — суть вопроса как-то изменится?

Comment: если я правильно понял суть вопроса, то вам нужно отписаться от события, которое прикреплено к этой кнопке (символу), либо заблокировать это событие

Comment: Да, все правильно мне нужно отписаться от события, я просто не знаю как это сделать и поэтому начал просто блокировать кнопки.
@ВиталийШебаниц

Comment: @andreymal 
У меня использован такой спецсимвол, который появляется в заказе рядом с выбранной позицией.

Comment: @Кирилл вам нужен [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Comment: `deleteIcon.style.pointerEvents = 'none'` попробуйте

Comment: @StrangerintheQ стоит тогда сказать, чтобы обратно запустить, понадобится `none` заменить на `auto`.... ps вы для меня открыли завесу...всегда думал что он только для svg

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц я обычно использую `all` чтобы вернуть в зад

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в документации пишет `all` только для `svg`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц document.removeEventListener('click', bindDeleteEvent);
вот так?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, я вроде тоже all писал и работало. Я думал, для svg только специфические... А спецификация - это именно спецификация или MDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отключить события мыши для любого элемента можно через css, только нужно понимать что оно будет унаследовано дочерними элементами

js:

```
deleteIcon.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
```

css:

```
.disabled {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

---

Вернуть обработку событий:

js:

```
deleteIcon.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
```

css:

```
.disabled {
   pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".block").forEach(b => {
  b.onclick = () => console.log(b.innerHTML);
})

document.querySelectorAll(".test").forEach(b => {
  b.style.pointerEvents="none";
})
```

```css
.block{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background-color:wheat;
  margin:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:40px;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

div.block:hover{
  background-color:red;
}
.disabled {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">1</div>
<div class="block" style="pointer-events:none">2</div>
<div class="block disabled">3</div>
<div class="block test">4</div>
<div class="block">5</div>
<div class="block test">6</div>
```

Comment: мне нужно сделать это только через js

Comment: @Кирилл 4 и 6 блок в моем примере

Comment: мне больше подходит вариант с removeEventListener. Только вот не могу понять, у меня есть вот такая функция:
function bindDeleteEvent(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var target = event.target;
        var closestPosition = target.closest('.position');
        closestPosition.remove();
    })
}

Как должен это должно выглядеть, вот так?:

document.removeEventListener('click',  bindDeleteEvent);       Извиняюсь за такое написание, только что зарегистрировался, не могу понять, как написать читаемо, как в коде.

Comment: @Кирилл описанный мной способ Вам тоже должен отлично подойти

Comment: @Кирилл в комментариях форматирование кода не работает. Но я добавил ваш текст к вопросу, там всё выглядит нормально.